# Erro ao separar arrays em PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma classe de PHP responsável pelo envio de notas fiscais, no entanto ela retorna o seguinte erro, como se estivesse tentando passar um array pra variável:

> ```
> [13-Mar-2018 14:08:26 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\...ToolsNFePHP.class.php on line 5212
> ```

Pelo código, a variável `$msg` já deveria enviar uma *string*, já tentei converter de *Array* para *String*, mas o erro continua.

**Segue o código:**

```
/**
 * pSetError
 * Adiciona descrição do erro ao contenedor dos erros
 *
 * @name pSetError
 * @param   string $msg Descrição do erro
 * @return  none
 */
private function pSetError($msg)
{
    $this->errMsg .= "$msg\n";
    $this->errStatus = true;
}
```

Isso acontece apenas nesse caso, outros objetos enviam funcionam normalmente. Acredito que possa estar agregando mais de uma mensagem de erro na mesma variável e ocasionando o erro, mas sem vê-lo não consigo corrigir.

Comment: Na verdade você está tentando concatenar os valores do array e não explodi/separar. Provavelmente você está passando uma *String* para o método `pSetError`, enquanto o correto seria passar um *Array*.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erros de Array to string conversion in em função PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282584/erros-de-array-to-string-conversion-in-em-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-php)

Comment: O código parece correto o que pode estar errado é argumento na chamada do método.

Comment: Utilize uma *string* ao invés de um *array*. Você pode utilizar o `implode(",", $array);` antes de acessar a função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que está dando  ( Array to string conversion ), você ta tentando separar um uma String em um Array, que são coisas diferentes.

```
    private function pSetError($msg = array())
{
    $MsgErro = explode(',', $msg);
    $this->errMsg .= "$MsgErro\n";
    $this->errStatus = true;
}
```

> implode — Junta elementos de uma matriz em uma string 
>   [Implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)
>
> explode — Divide uma string em strings
>   [Explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

Explode e Implode serve para "Strings" e não Array, caso queria quebrar o Array em "pedaços", você pode usar o [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php). Com ele você pode quebrar em vários pedaços que desejar;

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true));
```

Saída do código acima:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => e
        )

)
```

Você pode também usar o [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php)

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"


print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
```

O código a cima sairá assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => d
)
Array
(
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, reavaliando o código realmente ele deveria estar enviando uma string já, e não um array.

Comment: acabei editando a questão... acredito que agora fica mais claro.